# How does onUpdated work

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm currently trying to check wether there is a new update of my app before the whole app is loading, this in order to speed the loading up a bit.

So I was trying to figure out how and when the onUpdated function is called but I can't seem to find anything in the ST sources.

```
Ext.application({

  ...

  onUpdated: function() {
    var title, message;
    title   = 'Application Update';
    message = 'A new version of this site is available. Reload now?';
    Ext.Msg.confirm(title, message, function(buttonId) {
      if (buttonId === 'yes') {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Basically two questions :

**When is the onUpdated function called in the framework ?**

**How can I check wether there is an update or not before the whole app is loaded and rendered ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the detailed explanation by [Jacky Nguyen on Sencha Touch 2.x Forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188446-When-will-run-onUpdated-function-in-app.js&s=355d4be2ee9c201df292a74f07ac9bb3)!

Comment: "By comparing the latest checksum values with the ones locally stored inside Local Storage, the app knows exactly what file has changed, and pull down the delta for that item, then patch its local copy to make it identical to the latest one." Do you know where this is is happening in the framework ?