# When exactly does Sencha Touch 2 execute check for updates

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to fully understand how and when Sencha Touch 2 framework are executing the update checks. I know it happens when the HTML 5 app is refreshed in browser / webview, but how can I make it happen "manually". Reason is that we wrap the Sencha app in a webview, and it is often not recreated, the activity it just in the background, and therefore a full reload of the app is not done and the check for update request is not done. I want to be able somehow to force user to update, but for that I need to know exactly how the Sencha upgrade process internally work

Comment: window.location.reload(); ?

Comment: well, that would be the trivial solution, optimally I would like to do  a AJAX request in the background when use logs in to check if there are new updates, and if yes, I could do a window.location.reload()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901800/how-does-onupdated-work