# Sencha onUpdated() function & native apps

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have read much about this function and I understand how it works in the web environment.
This article gives a good explanation.
[How does onUpdated work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901800)

What I would like to know is how do I get this to work on Native Apps

Answer (score 2):

When you encapsulate a web app to build a native app using a framework like PhoneGap for example, you have to build the Sencha app in `package` mode that disable the use of the manifest, finally you have to copy the built app in the native OS specific folder of your app and build it to make the binary, so, the web app sources are inside your native binary and not downloaded from a server.

So, the "onUpdate" event is never triggered in native apps and you have to manually release a new version of the app every time you change the web app sources.

Comment: Well that method of creating native apps with Sencha is different from what I have done. However, to summarize, what you're saying is that building a native app disables the use of the cache.manifest and so onUpdated is never triggered?

Comment: yes. Sencha documentation tells to build app using `package` directive instead of `production` for using in native app. And that (you can check it yourself watching the producted `index.html` built file) disable the use of the manifest file. I've never used the native packager of Sencha because when I needed it that was broken (early version) both for Android and iOS, so I used PhoneGap packaging web app as I told you.

Comment: Finally, you don't really need the manifest caching file (and the "onUpdate" mechanism) in native app, and the reason is that all web app files are built inside the binary and not downloaded.

Comment: Yep. I agree. But I have been told to use sencha to create android app that will automatically notify when an update is available. I suspect they may have got confused with the web production version

Comment: You can use the built in notification system available in all OS (Android, iOS) that notify you when an upgrade is available for your app in the store. More, you can wrap the main web app in native way using, for example, PhoneGap, and write some line of code in native language to let the app check if there is a new version on its specific store, and notify the user from inside app. Theese are only some sort of "red hat" ideas to face your problem ;)